# angular-ui-bootstrap: disable group header after expanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a requirement to disable the collapse operation on click of the angular-ui-bootstrap accordion-group. It should expand on click but not collapse if clicked again, rather it should get collapsed on click of any other accordion-group(which is a default behavior. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `is-disabled` option of `accordion-group` directive for this?

Comment: add a flag kind of thing when click and check if it true or false do other way around https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion. Look this example

Comment: Yes thats part of the solution. But as a newbie I am trying to figure out how do I enable that back when I click another accordian-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same flag for `is-open` and `is-disabled` properties, like this:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
  <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.isOpen" is-disabled="group.isOpen">
    {{group.content}}
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

See little [demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/UdWkp7hbwOlxlM6ilvFX?p=preview)